# Fucnction giving NaN response when calling it through another function

Tags: javascript

If I use a click event to call this function it works fine:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("svg");

function relMouseCoords(event){
  var totalOffsetX = 0; //coordinates of corner of canvas
  var totalOffsetY = 0;
  var canvasX = 0;
  var canvasY = 0;
  var canvas = this; //what called the event

  do{
      totalOffsetX += canvas.offsetLeft - canvas.scrollLeft; //relative coordinates
      totalOffsetY += canvas.offsetTop - canvas.scrollTop;
  }
  while(canvas = canvas.offsetParent)

  canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
  canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;

  point = {x:canvasX, y:canvasY};

  console.log(point.x + " " + point.y);

  return point; //object returned
}
```

But when i try and call it through this function using a click event it returns an object with two NaN values inside:

```
function drawRectangle(event){
  var startPoint;

  startPoint = relMouseCoords(event);

  console.log(startPoint);
}
```

Could anyone please explain to me why this is? and if there is a fix for it? I would not like to use JQuery if anyone has responses to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: `var canvas = this;` could be the problem. In what context is the function getting called? To switch the relMouseCoords Function into the canvas context you can call the function like this: `relMouseCoords.call(canvasCtx, event);`

Comment: Just remove `var canvas = this;` and should work fine as you're already defining the canvas...

Comment: Why don't you "debug" it? Step through the logic in a debugger and watch the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in the comments on the original post. It was fixed by just removing `var canvas = this;`.